# NodeJS - "This type of response MUST not have a body..."

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

I've recently ran into a very interesting problem while writing a web app with node.js.
Essentially, all I am doing is serving the **index.html** page to the client.

Here is the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
        var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        if(path == '/'){
            console.log("LOADING INDEX...");
            openIndex(req, res);
            console.log("LOADING COMPLETE.")
        } else {
            res.write("Something went wrong...");
            res.end();
        }
    }
);

var openIndex = function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('./index.html', function(error, content){
        if(error){
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
        }
        else{
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
}
```

I've put some debugging statements just before and after the **index.html** page loads: *"LOADING INDEX..."* and *"LOADING COMPLETE"*.

Now, I have shared the link to my server with my Facebook friends so they can see my app. Most of the time, everything works as it should, but once in a while I get this error:

> LOADING INDEX...
>
> This type of response MUST NOT have a body. Ignoring data passed to end().

and just now I've also gotten:

> LOADING INDEX...
>
> This type of response MUST NOT have a body. Ignoring write() calls.

**The process never raches the *"LOADING COMPLETE"* statement.**

I've tried to reproduce this countless times (accessing my app on different machines, browsers, devices, OS-versions) but every time it works as it should.
I've looked around for other people having this problem, and it seems that somehow, a body is getting into a GET response? I'm not entirely sure what this means or how to fix my code to prevent that from happening. Also, I'm not sure what the clients that produce this error see? Do they get to see my app? (i.e. are these just warnings and as far as they are concerned everything is fine?)

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Xaan

Comment: A [HTTP request is formed of a Header and Body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). It seems that the request issued doesn't expect the body part back; e.g. a HEAD request.  I'm not sure *why* a browser would issue a request like this by itself, and neither have I see NodeJS log errors for that sort of thing. To check if this diagnostic is correct, you could log `req.method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using a static `index.html`, why not use `express.static` to serve it automatically?

```
app.use("/index.html", express.static(__dirname + '/index.html'));
```

This would cause expressjs to automatically handle `HEAD` requests, which should solve your problem.

Comment: That is a good idea. I would like to know, however, when a client loads the **index.html** page (with console.log("message").) How would I do that using expressjs?

Comment: Nevermind - I found the answer. You can log access with expressjs using app.use(express.logger()); Hopefully, the problem won't persist now.

Comment: Hmm... I took your advice and switched to serving with express. The problem still exists: **
'someipaddress - - [Sun, 15 Jul 2012 10:58:49 GMT] "HEAD /manager/html HTTP/1.0" 404 - "-" "-"**
Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: It might be a search crawler bot. Can you post the user agent string?

Comment: It took me a while, but thank you. I accepted your answer. The problem seems to be just random hackers from around the world trying to (without success) gain access to my server.